# Error 400: Bad Request, Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: php, laravel, apache, http-status-code-400

My website paroject is written with laravel framework and it configured with apache web server.

Some of requests in every pages get 400 error randomly with this message `"Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."`
I read some articles in about that and I think that's issue related to resources config, so
I increased below variables in `php.ini`:

- `memory_limit`

- `post_max_size`

- `upload_max_filesize`

 And I increased `LimitRequestFieldSize` in httpd.
But it's not worked for my issue.
Can anyone help me?
What can I do?
Any configs or any work?
What is my problem and how can I solve this issue.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Seeing how you're trying to get images, I don't think PHP is involved here at all. Probably check your webserver configuration for this particular website. Might be worth reading up on what a 400 error means at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400 however the main point to see here is that this is a **client error** so in the majority of cases it's caused because the client sent a bad request

Comment: Probably your image are too large or there is some broken header, as I can see you have also 404 not found, it could be some rewrite/proxy rule that creates a wrong header.

Comment: @apokryfos Is there any configs or anything which I must be do that?